# Button ActionPerfomed move string from JList to JList

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jlist, cannot-find-symbol

I am working on an assessment for a program I would like to participate in. I am still a bit turned around on how to interpret, understand or properly use the "tutorials" located at Tutorials Point which were provided by the program.

Jlist created using Netbeans 8.1 --> JFrame Form GUI Builder

```
public class Window extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form for BootcampAssessmentGui
 */
public Window() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    controlsbuttonGroup = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    partsScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    partsList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    buildScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    buildList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    removeButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    loadMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    saveMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Devereaux Assessment");

    partsList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "Case", "Motherboard", "CPU", "RAM", "GPU", "HDD", "PSU" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    partsScrollPane.setViewportView(partsList);

    buildScrollPane.setViewportView(buildList);

    addButton.setText(">>");
    addButton.setToolTipText("Add Parts to Build list");
    controlsbuttonGroup.add(addButton);
    addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    removeButton.setText("<<");
    removeButton.setToolTipText("Remove Parts from Build list");
    controlsbuttonGroup.add(removeButton);
    removeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            removeButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    fileMenu.setText("File");

    loadMenuItem.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_L, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    loadMenuItem.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cooksys/assessment/arrow95.png"))); // NOI18N
    loadMenuItem.setText("Load");
    fileMenu.add(loadMenuItem);

    saveMenuItem.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    saveMenuItem.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cooksys/assessment/floppy13.png"))); // NOI18N
    saveMenuItem.setText("Save");
    fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);

    exitMenuItem.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_X, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    exitMenuItem.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cooksys/assessment/exit18.png"))); // NOI18N
    exitMenuItem.setText("Exit");
    exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

    jMenuBar1.add(fileMenu);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(partsScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 209, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(addButton)
                .addComponent(removeButton))
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addComponent(buildScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 209, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(buildScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 279, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(partsScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 279, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(125, 125, 125)
                    .addComponent(addButton)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(removeButton)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    System.exit(0);
}                                            

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // add Parts to buildList
  for (Object selectedValue : partsList.getSelectedValuesList()) {
      buildList.addElement(selectedValue);
      partsList.removeElement(selectedValue);
      int  iSelected = partsList.getSelectedIndex();
      if (iSelected == -1) {
          return;
      }
    }
}                                         

private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // remove Parts from buildList
    for (Object selectedValue : buildList.getSelectedValuesList()) {
      partsList.addElement(selectedValue);
      buildList.removeElement(selectedValue);
      int  iSelected = buildList.getSelectedIndex();
      if (iSelected == -1) {
          return;
      }
    }
}                                            

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Window().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
private javax.swing.JList<String> buildList;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane buildScrollPane;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup controlsbuttonGroup;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem exitMenuItem;
private javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem loadMenuItem;
private javax.swing.JList<String> partsList;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane partsScrollPane;
private javax.swing.JButton removeButton;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem saveMenuItem;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I am getting errors *cannot find symbol* -
symbol: method addElement(Object) 
location: variable partsList type of Jlist

the error reads very straight-forward to me. My problem is most of the examples I've seen are using DefaultListModel. NetBeans is using the AbstractListModel method.

I have reviewed the following references:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DualJListwithbuttonsinbetween.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#scrollingapi

But I honestly feel like I am not properly understanding how these sources are to be used to debug. I feel like I am not properly using the Object --> String based on this bit of code:

```
 private void clearDestinationSelected() {
Object selected[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  destListModel.removeElement(selected[i]);
}
destList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

}

I will be including this request for assistance in the code via comment. I'm not a cheater. I have looked, worked, searched and thought about this for a few days. At this point I feel like asking for help would be prudent.

Comment: *"My problem is most of the examples I've seen are using DefaultListModel. NetBeans is using the AbstractListModel method."*  This is the point where you need to either a) Work out how to get the IDE to do what ***you*** want. b) Or dump the IDE and learn how to code Java.

Comment: `NetBeans is using the AbstractListModel method.` - well don't. Use the DefaultListModel. Your problem is with the IDE, not Swing. I suggest you learn how to create a DefaultListModel, add data to the model and then add the model to the JList. The Hire/Fire demo example from the Swing tutorial does everything you need. It shows you how to 1) initially load data into a model and then 2) dynamically change the model. Download that demo and use it as a starting point instead of letting the IDE generate code for you.

Answer (score 2):

The API will help you some here, since if you check out the JList API, you'll see that your compiler was right, that JList does not have an `addElement(...)` method, but don't lose heart -- the DefaultListModel class **does** have this method, and you can extract this from your JList by calling `getModel()`, and then call `addElement(...)` on the extracted model.

Edit: no good, you're using your own model derived from AbstractListModel -- you will need to make your model non-abstract -- give it a class name, and then give your Model class an addElement method. Either that or more simply, use a DefaultListModel object that you fill with your data.